# How do I set the position of an image view in a relative layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to position an image below a `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout` but it doesn't work. when i set its position using `android:layout_below`. This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ccc"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/app_details_1" 
android:text="@string/app_details_1" 
android:textColor="#347"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="9pt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>  

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/logo"
android:src="@drawable/secs"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/appdetails_1" <!-- I'm setting it here -->
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Instead it just places the image at the top left of the screen. How do I position it? Is `layout_below` a wrong positioning code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a mistake in your xml. Must be

```
android:layout_below="@id/app_details_1"
```

Comment: To completely explain this: `+id` is a shortcut that this id has to be created. When referencing an existing id, it's just `id`. Official doc regarding this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

Comment: Also the typo `appdetails_1` instead of `app_details_1`

Comment: @user7777777777 Yes, it's the only mistake. Plus sign is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

it should be ok, but first try to make sure the textView is positioned on top by using layout_alignParentTop="true" for the textView and see if it does the trick.